# Compressed JSON is bigger than non-compressed version

Tags: json, go, gzip

I'll try to clear up my question.

myJSON is a simple JSON string.
`len(myJSON)` = 78

e is `json.Marshal(myJSON)`

From what I understand, e is now a `[]byte`

Then I gzip e like this:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
gz := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
gz.Write(e)
gz.Close()
```

And `buf.Len()` = 96

So... why is my compressed buffer bigger than the original non-compressed string?

Edit: It's hilarious the trolls that down vote a question when someone is trying to understand WHY something is happening. Guess I should just blindly accept it and not ask.

Comment: Because the original is only 78 bytes. Gzip doesn't magically make bytes smaller; it needs a large enough corpus to find enough repeated byte sequences for the compression to be effective.

Comment: For reference, gzip uses the DEFLATE algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE

Comment: @Adrian. Thanks. To me this seems to be an issue. A lot of people blindly use gzip on their json thinking it's becoming smaller. I guess to be sure, you'd have to go through an exercise like this in your code to determine if gzip is worth it.

Comment: Any tool will be misused by those who choose to use it without fully understanding it. Gzip is ineffective on small payloads and any payload that does not have a lot of repeated byte sequences (e.g. anything already compressed like a JPEG or MP3, or encrypted data). Generally gzip begins to become effective on plain text around the 500~1000 byte mark, and gets more effective with larger payloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**gzip** will add a **header** and make some changes to the original data. For the case, the original data is really small it will not guarantee compressed data will smaller than original data.

So if your program will constantly deal with the small data like this. Compress data use compress library may not a good idea. Some time we serialize the data into **binary stream** for the case that data is constantly small.

**Go gzip package ref:**

> Package gzip implements reading and writing of gzip format compressed
> files, as specified in RFC 1952.

[RFC1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952)

**gzip format and header:**

http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gzip.html

Answer (score 10):

It is physically impossible to design a lossless compression algorithm that will reduce the size of every input document.

As a thought experiment, imagine that such a compressor existed and could compress any document by at least one bit.

Now lets say that I generate every document that is at most N bits long.  That is 1 document of length 0, 2 of length 1, 4 of length 2, etc.  This sequence works out to `2^(N+1)-1` total documents.

If we run all the documents through the compressor, the compressed versions will all be at most N-1 bits long.  That means there can be at most `2^N-1` compressed documents, which is fewer than we started with.  Either the compression system is lossy (in which case decompression won't necessarily give us the original document), or some documents must grow in size when compressed.

Comment: The old story goes: if you could create a lossless algoritmn that could reduce every input by at least 1 bit, repeating it enough times (on the previous run's output), you could compress the entire internet into a single bit...